# AngularJS Scope vs. Bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-bind

I'm just curious about this issue I have:

In the MainController I have this:

```
$scope._layout = { currentYear: moment().format('YYYY') };
```

While in the html layout page I have this.

```
[...]

<body class="" ng-controller="MainController">

<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTAINER-->
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<!-- END CONTAINER -->

<span>{{_layout.currentYear}}</span>

[...]
```

This above won't work, {{_layout.currentYear}} displays nothing, but if I change it to be ng-bind, then it works.

```
[...]

<body class="" ng-controller="MainController">

<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTAINER-->
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<!-- END CONTAINER -->

<span ng-bind="_layout.currentYear"></span>

[...]
```

Why the {{_layout.currentYear}} syntax doesn't work?

Comment: Should work fine....

Comment: Works fine for me: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ird3GyRnVmQF4rTqi6F6?p=preview)

Comment: that's really weird... probably I have something more in the page blocking that...

Comment: `{{foo}}` is automatically "translated" to `<span ng-bind="foo"></span>` so there should be absolutely no differences between them.